# Git: Diff a list of files

Tags: git, git-svn, git-diff, changelist

Is it possible to add a list of files somewhere to a changelist or file or something, and to run `git diff commit1 commit2 myListOfFiles` and to get the diff of just that list of files? Or is it possible to create a macro that expands to that list? and to be able to remove and add from that list or change it?

This would be super-useful for creating patches for just certain files, not having to type down the paths for all 20 files I want to diff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
git diff commit1 commit2 -- $(cat /path/to/listfile)
```

You can alias this command by the following line to your `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    listdiff = "!f() { git diff $1 $2 -- $(cat \"$3\"); }; f"
```

and call it with

```
git listdiff commit1 commit2 path/to/file
```

Comment: this is a very good method to go, I'll use it till something better comes along, thanks! :)
I see that you can do some bash-like scripting in the `gitconfig`.
Isn't it possible to keep these files inside `gitconfig`, not other file?
Also can you give me some link to some references regarding this kind of scripting inside `gitconfig`?

Comment: @JasonSwartz What do you mean “other file”? You can put this in any git config, that is `~.gitconfig`, `.git/config`, `/etc/gitconfig` and so on, see [`man git-config`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) for details. If you start an alias with `!`, the rest of the line is simply executed in your shell, so, this is not “bash-like”, that's true bash (or whichever shell you use).

Comment: I meant, not to keep a separate file for the list of files. to store that list of files in the `gitconfig`.

Comment: @JasonSwartz Seems quite useless? I mean, you normally want to have one such file per repo, so keeping it in `.gitconfig` doesn't make any sense.